Bounded diameter implies compact closure
I've got this question about basic analysis, I can't find an elegant proof of the following statement:
If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $A\subseteq X$ is set whose diameter is finite, then its closure is compact.
I tried using the definition of compactness using sequences but got nothing out of it :(

This is not true. It is true in Euclidean spaces (equipped with their usual metrics) by Heine-Borel theorem but false in general.

This is false. Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d$ defined as $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$.
Then, $\mathbb{R}$ has diameter $1$, but it is its own closure, and it is not compact, because there is no finite subcover of $\{\{x\}: x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ (notice that all $\{x\}$ are open because $\{x\}=B(x,1/2)).$
